# boost property_tree adding nodes in a loop

Tags: c++, arrays, xml, boost, boost-propertytree

How do you add nodes to a property tree while looping a array?

This is probably a simple thing but I just don't understand how to work with boost_property_tree.

I have an array of values that I want to add to a property tree and output it as xml. If I hardcode the nodes and add them by hand to root node it works but if I try to do it from inside a loop the xml is invalid, contains only one node from the array and none of the xml nodes are terminate.

It's a variable length array of data so hardcoding the nodes are not possible. Doing something like this simply doesn't work. And I don't understand why?

```
ptree listnode;
std::vector<data> dataarray= ...
for(auto data : dataarray)
{
    ptree node;
    ...

    listnode.add_child("value", node)
}
...
```

What I want is something like this:

```
<list>
    <value active="true">12</value>
    <value active="true">44</value>
    <value active="true">23</value>
</list>
```

But the resulting xml looks like this:

```
<list>
    <value active="true">
```

It just stops after the first value node. No exceptions or anything so I'm assuming that either my property_tree is invalid or its the xml_parser::write_xml that fails to create the xml.

Most likely I have misunderstood how to use boost::property_tree. But really, outputting a list must be a pretty simple thing?

Comment: could it be you're not actually using `add_child` (but, e.g. `put`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50a23f20cb843f68)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::property_tree;

int main() {
    ptree pt;

    auto& list = pt.add_child("list", ptree{});

    for (auto data : { 12, 44, 23 })
        list.add("value", data)
            .add("<xmlattr>.active", true);

    xml_parser::write_xml(std::cout, pt);
}
```

Resulting XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<list>
    <value active="true">12</value>
    <value active="true">44</value>
    <value active="true">23</value>
</list>
```

Comment: Thanks :) This example was just what I needed. Well kind of, first I really did not see what you did differently from me but as your example worked and my very similar code did not I spent some time staring at it. And yeah I'm feeling pretty stupid. Turns out capturing the return value from add_child by value is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: @DbgCtrl hehe. That would explain :) Nice that you found the cause!